# How we can translate drupal error message

Tags: translation, drupal-8

Can we translated below drupal error message in turkish language from where to translate?

```
Temporarily Unavailable
The website that you're trying to reach is having technical difficulties and is currently unavailable.

We are aware of the issue and are working hard to fix it. Thank you for your patience.
```

Want to translate drupal error message. Tried to search message in code but didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

In durpal there is a core module called content-language enable it hopefully this gonna help you.

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y56o4.png)
[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gz4U.png)